# <!DOCTYPE> html/template

Tags: html, go

I've got this simple go lang webserver that does nothing more but parsing some data into an external HTML file and serve that file to the webserver.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

type Event struct {
    Name string
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    e := Event{ Name: "Melt! Festival" }
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("events.html")
    t.Execute(w, e)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil)
}
```

But whenever I try to parse the HTML file with the  set it parses my html-page as text in stead of rendering the HTML in the browser

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Event</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Event: {{.Name}}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I leave the `<!DOCTYPE>` out of the HTML-file it renders it just fine.

Can anyone tell me why this is because I'm really curious? I spent two hours searching for the cause of my go code not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doctype declaration is incorrect, thus having an effect opposite from the desired one : it is probably interpreted by the browser as signifying the document **isn't** HTML.

Use this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

See [reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html).

Comment: That's it, I'm somehow used to not including the " html" part. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DOCTYPE html in your file instead?